# the trait bound `ReadError: linfa::Float` is not satisfied

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Im trying to convert a CSV to a 2D array to train a model using the Linfa crate.
From what i understand, the function is trying to return 2 errors at the same time. But i wont want to create another error type.
Though my array_from_csv method cant seem to return an accepted result here is my code:

```
use csv::ReaderBuilder;
use linfa::prelude::*;
use linfa::Dataset;
use linfa_linear::{Result, TweedieRegressor};
use ndarray::prelude::*;
use ndarray::Axis;
use ndarray_csv::{Array2Reader, ReadError};
use std::io::Read;
// Convert CSV bytes into 2D array
fn array_from_csv<R: Read>(
    csv: R,
    has_headers: bool,
    separator: u8,
) -> Result<Array2<f64>, ReadError> {
    // parse CSV
    let mut reader = ReaderBuilder::new()
        .has_headers(has_headers)
        .delimiter(separator)
        .from_reader(csv);

    // extract ndarray
    reader.deserialize_array2_dynamic();
}
```

That i am calling here:

```
fn get_dataset() -> Dataset<f64, Ix1> {
let data = include_bytes!("examples/data/AMZN_data.csv");
let data = array_from_csv(&data[..], true, b',').unwrap();
let targets = include_bytes!("examples/data/AMZN_targets.csv");
let targets = array_from_csv(&targets[..], true, b',')
    .unwrap()
    .column(0)
    .to_owned();

let feature_names = vec![
    "date",
    "open",
    "high",
    "low",
    "close",
    "adj_close",
    "volume",
];

Dataset::new(data, targets).with_feature_names(feature_names)
}
```

I then get:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `ReadError: linfa::Float` is not satisfied
  --> src/linear_regression.rs:15:6
   |
15 | ) -> Result<Array2<f64>, ReadError> {
   |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `linfa::Float` is not implemented for `ReadError`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `linfa::Float`:
             f32
             f64
note: required by a bound in `LinearError`
  --> /home/theod/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/linfa-linear-0.7.0/src/error.rs:10:25
   |
10 | pub enum LinearError<F: Float> {
   |                         ^^^^^ required by this bound in `LinearError`
```

Here is my Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "rust-programs-library"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
ta = "0.4.0"
csv = "1.1.0"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
linfa = "0.7.0"
linfa-linear = "0.7.0"
ndarray = "0.15.6"
ndarray-csv = "0.5.2"
flate2 = "1.0.28"

[dev-dependencies]
assert_approx_eq = "1.0.0"
bencher = "0.1.5"
rand = "0.6.5"
bincode = "1.3.1"
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete - it is missing the imports you are using, and the relevant parts of `Cargo.toml`. The function you provided is incomplete because the trailing `;` would result in a different error. With that fixed, it appears to compile. You're not showing how you're using anything from `linfa`, so it's hard to tell where the error comes from. Include more information and you'll be much more likely to get meaningful help.

Comment: @user4815162342 i added the full function! My goal is to create a new Dataset from a target and data file using linear regression. I understand that the function cant return both errotypes at once without me creating a new one that merges both...

Comment: Your `array_from_csv` is still not the version you're actually using (the version in the question doesn't compile), and you still didn't show `Cargo.toml` and imports.

Comment: @user4815162342 modified again

Answer (score 0):

The reported issue comes from `use linfa_linear::Result`, which replaces the built-in `Result` in your scope with a non-standard definition provided by `linfa_linear`.

If you remove that `use`, you get a different error, a type mismatch between unit type and the declared `Result`. This is due to the extraneous `;` at the end of `array_from_csv()`. Once you remove that, `array_from_csv()` compiles.

The remaining error is:

```
26 | fn get_dataset() -> Dataset<f64, Ix1> {
   |                     ----------------- expected `DatasetBase<ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f64>, Dim<[usize; 2]>>, ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<Dim<[usize; 1]>>, Dim<[usize; 2]>>>` because of return type
...
45 |     Dataset::new(data, targets).with_feature_names(feature_names)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Dim<[usize; 1]>`, found `f64`
   |
   = note: expected struct `DatasetBase<_, ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<Dim<[usize; 1]>>, Dim<[usize; 2]>>>`
              found struct `DatasetBase<_, ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f64>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>>`
```

...but I can't help with that one.